# Is there a way to bind Lua member variable as a call to C/C++ function with the name of that variable

Tags: c++, c, lua

I'm totally new to Lua. From what I understand it is possible to bind Lua variables and methods to ones on the C/C++ side.

But is it possible to bind a user type variable to the call of the C/C++ function which may look like properties on the Lua side ?

Example:

```cpp
// C++
struct player {
  int get_value(const std::string& property) const {
    auto it = values.find(name);

    if (it != values.end()) {
      return it->second;
    }

    return -1;
  }

  std::map<std::string, int> values;
};
```

And on the Lua side:

```
-- Lua
p = player.new()
print(p.score)
```

So when I call `p.score` in Lua, it gets translated to the call to the `player::get_value` function on C++ side with the value of `property` "score" ?

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to @Vlad for the directions!

I came up using [sol2](https://github.com/ThePhD/sol2) which is in my opinion a very nice  C++ library binding to Lua!

Here is how it can be done with sol2:

```cpp
struct Player {
  sol::object get(const std::string& key, sol::this_state state) {
    const auto& it = values.find(key);

    if (it != values.cend()) {
      return sol::make_object(state, it->second);
    }

    return sol::lua_nil;
  }

  std::map<std::string, int> values;
};

int main() {
  Player player;

  player.values.emplace("score", 123);

  sol::state lua;

  lua.open_libraries(sol::lib::base);
  lua.new_usertype<Player>("Player", sol::meta_function::index, &Player::get);
  lua.set("player", &player);

  lua.script(R"(
    print("Player score: ", player.score)
  )");
  return 0;
}
```

Console output

```
Player score:   123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object `player` should have metatable set with fields `__index`/`__newindex` set to C function that will be called when Lua is trying to read or write the field that doesn't exist in the Lua object.

Normally the Lua object representing the native object (`player` in your case) will be a `userdata`, either storing the pointer to the C++ object, or hosting it within its storage.

The metamethods `__index`/`__newindex` will receive in arguments the reference to the object being queried, the key value (e.g. your `score` field), and the value to store in case of `__newindex` metamethod. So you can find your native object and desired property easily.

Some people prefer using existing binding solutions - tolua++/sol/luabind/etc, but it's very simple to implement required functionality yourself.